# Is it possible to recall a Schengen visa application and receive the passport sooner?

Tags: visas, schengen, passports

The passport may be needed urgently for some reason. It would be helpful if we had a chance to recall the visa application and receive the passport before the regular visa processing time (e.g. 15 days).

Is there any possibility for that?

Comment: I am not aware of any explicit provisions for that in the relevant EU regulations. Whether and how you can do it would depend on the specific consulate. I assume you would forfeit you fee and the application and would have to start from scratch.

Comment: @Relaxed I see. I just looked over the Visa Code, nothing relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was filing my daughter's passport via VFS Global, and thought to have made an error in application, this is how I learned they **do** have application recall.

You could fill a form with them and get your passport back to you with no visa and probably much sooner. However I wasn't able to try that, since they were able to correct my application on the spot by calling the embassy. So I have no idea how fast would recall be.

No idea if it applies to embassies in general and/or other visa intermediaries.